# Is it possible to have different fields associated with users in different groups?

Tags: users

We're developing a client site in CraftCMS that has 2 different frontend user groups. I know it's possible to set up custom fields for users but I'd like to set up different additional profile fields for each Group i.e. Group A has one set of custom fields and Group B has another. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible in Craft via the the Control Panel.

If you are managing user profiles from the front-end, you can manage different fields for different user groups manually.

A few considerations:

- You can't set a field to required in Craft if it will be optional for one of the user groups on the front-end and not the other.  You may have to manage required fields in another way.
- An admin with direct access to Users in the CP will have no signal in the UI as to which fields belong to which User Groups.

Comment: Fair enough! It's a shame this isn't supported at present. There's quite a few use cases for different types of frontend user i.e. Agents/Clients. I guess you could model these separately using a plugin if the functionality got too complex for CP users anyway.

Comment: Looks like it's on the feature request list if you want to share your use cases!  I agree it'd be handy.  I think it's just a bit tricky in implementation: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7197199-ability-to-hide-or-disable-fields-based-on-a-user